Use regex in Openshift haproxy router path
I'm working on migrating a helms chart from nginx.ingress.kubernetes syntax to  haproxy.router.openshift.i.o. (openshift v4)
is it possible to have regex in router path like we did in ngnix? i can't find any documentation on this
e.g.
nginx syntax
  - name: APP_NAME
    port: 4200
    path: /payment(.*)

ingress:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"

haproxy
  - name: APP_NAME
    port: 4200
    path: /payment(.*)

ingress:
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/use-regex: "true" ???


What you're asking for is a feature request that is currently in Red Hat's backlog.
Looks like it was supposed to have its investigation completed on 4/12/2024, but its been open since 5/01/2022.
